# Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected token < in rails link_to code

Tags: ruby-on-rails

[image]I am trying to use ujs approach to invoke a custom function in the controller. I get this error :

> Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected token <

I tried directly using the custom-made url. That doesn't work either.

rake routes

```
   room_connected PUT    /rooms/:room_id/connected(.:format) rooms#connected
        rooms GET    /rooms(.:format)                    rooms#index
              POST   /rooms(.:format)                    rooms#create
```

`routes.rb`

```
 resources :rooms do
   put "connected", :to => "rooms#connected", as: :connected
 end
```

Js function in `show.html.erb`

```
session.on("connectionCreated", function(event) {
  connectionCount++;
  // jqueryFunction("Call from js to jquery");
   <%= link_to @room.name, room_connected_path(@room), :remote => true, :method => "put" %>
  displayConnectionCount();
});
```

Function defined in `room_controller.rb`

```
def connected
    binding.pry
    @room = Room.find params[:id]
    # @room.update_attributes(params[:name])
end
```

`Error 1:`
6:158 Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected token < for the line `` <%= link_to @room.name, room_connected_path(@room), :remote => true, :method => "put" %>` which gets translated as below:
`<a data-remote="true" rel="nofollow" data-method="put" href="/rooms/6/connected">uma7</a> ``

`Error 2:`
     The "connected" function defined in the controller is not being called.
Please advise. Thank you

Tried Ajax:

```
   session.on("connectionCreated", function(event) {
  console.log("connectionCreated");
  console.log(room.id);
  connectionCount++;
  // jqueryFunction("Call from js to jquery");
   $.ajax({
    type: "PUT",
    data: JSON.stringify({ room: {name: 'New_room'}, _method:'put' }),
    url: "/rooms/" + room.id + "/connected",
    contentType: 'application/json'
}).done(function( msg )
{
    alert( "Data Saved: " + msg );
});
```

});
This throws the: `jquery.self-ee.js?body=1:10255 PUT http://localhost:3000/rooms/6/connected 500 (Internal Server Error)`

Server Logs:

```
Started PUT "/rooms/undefined/connected" for 127.0.0.1 at 2019-01-06 09:29:13 -0800
Processing by RoomsController#connected as */*
  Parameters: {"room"=>{"name"=>"New_room"}, "room_id"=>"undefined"}

From: /Users/us186007/Desktop/WebApps/goldenyears/app/controllers/rooms_controller.rb @ line 39 RoomsController#connected:

    36: def connected
    37:     binding.pry
    38:     # @room = Room.find params[:id]
 => 39:     @room.update_attributes(params[:name])
    40: end

[1] pry(#<RoomsController>)> @room
=> nil
```

Comment: And what do you have in server log when you try AJAX version?

Comment: The problem I am having is that the `Room` object is a rails view object and it is not visible in js scope. How can I pass the `Room` view object to javascript? Currently the `@room` value in controller is nil. I have edited the question to include the details of this issue. Thank you

Comment: Figured it out. ` var room_id = <%= @room.id %>` is the way to pass an object from rails view to js

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The issue is your ruby is in a javascript block, so it thinks it is javascript. Escape the javascript like:

`<%= j link_to @room.name, room_connected_path(@room), :remote => true, :method => "put" %>`

or 
`<%= escape_javascript link_to @room.name, room_connected_path(@room), :remote => true, :method => "put" %>`

As well - append the link to your DOM like:

`$('#link').append(<%= j link_to... %>)`

outside the js:

Comment: You are right. I think the issue is the ruby code in javascript block. I tried adding `j` but I get the same syntax error. I have attached the screenshot of the issue.

Comment: Hmm... did you try `escape_javascript` as well?

Comment: Also - what exactly are you trying to do here? You might want to try appending the link to a DOM element. Because as of now, it's saying 'do this javascript and here's a link'. But it's not sure what you're wanting to do with that link. I adjusted my answer to reflect this

Comment: I want to change the value in `Room` table once the connection has been established. Javascript function `session.on("connectionCreated",...) ` and from here I want to update a value of a column in a record of Room table. I also tried using ajax. But I am having issues with that too.

Comment: So, the `link_to` is only to provide a clickable button to the user. You'll want to stick with AJAX and POST/PUT to the controller to update values in the db.

Comment: I don't even want the link_to. I want a proper way to update a value in a row of `Room` from this function `session.on("connectionCreated",...).

Comment: I tried your suggestion: `$('#link').append` and I still get the error: ` $('#link').append(<a data-remote=\"true\" rel=\"nofollow\" data-method=\"put\" href=\"/rooms/6/connected\">uma7<\/a>)
      `

Comment: Either way - to accomplish what you're wanting, you'll want to use AJAX

Comment: I tried ajax. I get a 500 error. I have attached the ajax code and the error in the question

Answer (score 1):

You fill a JS function with a tag generated by

```
  <%= link_to @room.name, room_connected_path(@room), :remote => true, :method => "put" %>
```

so it should return a valid JS, not just HTML.

I'm not sure what you're trying to achieve here, but I'd start with wrapping the generated HTML in quotes to make it a correct JS string:

```
session.on("connectionCreated", function(event) {
  connectionCount++;
  // jqueryFunction("Call from js to jquery");
   '<%= link_to @room.name, room_connected_path(@room), :remote => true, :method => "put" %>'
  displayConnectionCount();
});
```

Comment: Thanks so much for your helpful comment. I wrapped the link_to in single quotes as you suggested and I am getting the syntax for the line: ` ''<a data-remote="true" rel="nofollow" data-method="put" href="/rooms/6/connected">uma7</a>''`

Comment: I am trying to change the name of the room once the connection has been established. The `session.on("connectionCreated") is a callback function which is called once connection has been established by the session. From this callback function, I am trying to call a function in the controller "connected" and update the table "Room" with a new name.

Comment: My bad: I didn't notice there was an extra quote. I removed it and there are no more errors. Thanks so much!

Comment: But it is still not calling the function "connected" defined in the controller.

Comment: I doubt that the line `link_to` is executed after adding single quotes.